# Issue downloading images using image_downloader package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So, I have been successful in downloading an image from a firebase URL and storing it in the device, The issue that I am facing is that it also downloads a file with the same name as the downloaded image, but without file type.

Example, downloading Image.jpg will also download a file named Image, and it is visible within the device.

```
saveImage(Message message) async {
String url = message.photoURL;
try {
  var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(
    url,
    destination: AndroidDestinationType.custom(directory: 'exampleDir'),
  );
  if (imageId == null) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Image Saved!'),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {});
  });
  if (imageId == null) {
    return;
  }
} on PlatformException catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

}

[image: Issue with downloading using Image_Downloader package]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you can give the postId as the image name or current timestamp.
Currently seems like its using currentTimestamp.works fine

Comment: It downloads fine, I want it to download as the current date and time, but if you notice next to it, there is another file with the same name but without a file type